# Delete Many to Many Using Entity Framework and Unit Of Work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get list of Student subject from their former class and remove them first so that when promoting the student to the next class, I will get the class subjects and then add them to that student, but all the approaches that I have aren't working for me.

this is the student Model

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        Subjects = new Collection<Subject>();
    }
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

this is the controller that is posting the action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Promot_Primary(int[] ChkBx, int AliasId)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var id in ChkBx)
        {
            // this is where am getting all the former class subjects
            var subjectIds = _courseService.GetAllStudentSubject(id)
                                           .Select(x => x.Id); 
            foreach (var item in subjectIds)
            {
                _studentService.RemoveSubject(item, id);
            }
        }
        ViewBag.message = true;
    }
}
```

here is the service that is not responding

```
public void RemoveSubject(int subjectId, int studentId)
{
    var student = UnitOfWork.Student.GetById(studentId);
    var subject = UnitOfWork.Subject.GetById(subjectId); 

    if (subject == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    student.Subjects.Remove(subject);
    UnitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Check if there is any thing that I am missing that is not allowing it to respond to remove...
Adding is working perfectly well but Remove isn't.

I just found out that when getting the student by Id inside the service the along with all the properties, the Subject count is 0 that's why it cant Remove it cause there is nothing inside the subjects property How can i Include the Subject when getting Student by Id please.

Comment: Do you know at which stage it isn't working? If you step through the RemoveSubject method a line at a time check the following. Is the student being returned correctly? If so does it have the Subjects collection set correctly? Is the subject being returned?

Comment: Yes, The subjects are return correctly to the list when using break point to check line by line.. I find out that there is an error when it Hit the student.subject.remove(subject)

Comment: I just found out that when getting the student by Id inside the service the along with all the properties, the Subject count is 0 that's why it cant Remove it cause there is nothing inside the subjects property

How can i Include the Subject when getting Student by Id please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something like

UnitOfWork.Update(student);

then you will do

UnitOfWork.Commit();

The update method will attach the student to your ORM, or do whatever you need to do with it